# How can I search an object of arrays that have no given properties?

Tags: arrays, csv, object, search

I am creating a small app that searches for the row in a .csv file based on a barcode. The objects she has to work with do not have the property:value structure that I normally see. Additionally, each folder has a different set of data, all of which, have these kinds of objects.

**Standard (?) Object Structure:**
{ name: "Bangladesh", continent: "Asia" },
{ name: "Portugal", continent: "Europe" }

**.csv  Object:**
{ "007B3":"007B3" "A01":"A01" "21018514T1":"21018514T1" }

The first prop:val stays the same for all 96 files, the second and third prop:val pairs are all different.

How can I search for an object using the third prop:val (barcode) pair?

I haven't seen anything online about how to handle this kind of structure.  When I console.log() the file, the .csv file looked like a "normal" object, but I don't know how to search these files with objects that look like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your question is very broad, and it's not clear which language / environment you are using. You do mention `console.log()` which indicates Javascript. But then you should edit the question accordingly.  For searching, since your csv content is not a proper object format anyway, have you tried match by regular expression, treating the csv not as object but a regular string ?

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, the original focus was on the structure of the "object" itself. I called it an "object" because the FireFox browser dev tool inspector displayed them as such. Hence the confusion on my part. The environment is React js with Javascript. I didn't even think about trying regex... I'll try it! Is there a reason for this kind of layout? Is it just how the csv files are packaged. Thanks MyICQ, I appreciate the insight!

Comment: Hey! Quick follow-up... the regex worked perfectly. All quotes have been removed. Thank you so much for the help! All the best!! How can I select your column as the best (and only) answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have you have a normal structure in JSON format, it's simple to modify and search

```
[ 
  { name: "Bangladesh", continent: "Asia" }, 
  { name: "Portugal", continent: "Europe" } 
]
```

in your case, the data will *look* like a JSON structure but is not:

`{ "007B3":"007B3" "A01":"A01" "21018514T1":"21018514T1" }`

If the structure is not JSON,  but still somewhat structured, you can treat it as a string.  For this purpose, regular expressions are perfect.

There are different ways to do things on the target string with regular expressions, depending on exact need. It can be split, or captured into elements.

One example is to apply `(?:"\w+":"\w+"\s){2}"(\w+)":"(\w+)"` which will capture last two elements separately:

```
      $1 ==> 21018514T1
      $2 ==> 21018514T1
```

The regular expression can be modified to specific needs. Example, `(?:"\w+":"\w+"\s){2}("\w+":"\w+")`  which captures `$1 ==>  "21018514T1":"21018514T1"`